# Undefined property error when refreshing map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Below is the full code of my Google Maps javascript file. What I'm trying to do is first initialise the map, then dynamically add a marker and refresh the map.

```
// GLOBALS
var map;

function refreshMap() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
    map.setCenter(map.get('originalCenter'));
}

function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
       scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      originalCenter: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832)
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
}

// Initialise Map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Add a Marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
    map: map,
    title: 'Marker'
});

// Refresh
refreshMap();
```

I'm getting the following error when `refreshMap()` is run:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined          main.js:15
```

Is this the correct way to refresh the map?

Comment: what event triggers the refreshMap function?  The way your code currently runs is it sets up the initialize function to run when the page load event fires, then creates a marker (map is not yet initialized as the page load event has not fired), then calls refreshMap (again before the page load event so the map is _still_ not initialized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code currently runs is it sets up the initialize function to run when the page load event fires, then creates a marker (map is not yet initialized as the page load event has not fired), then calls refreshMap (again before the page load event so the map is still not initialized). The code below triggers the refreshMap function when the button is clicked, but it can't be run until the page is loaded and the initialize function has run.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egrLLkxw/)

```
// GLOBALS
var map;

function refreshMap() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(map.get('originalCenter'));
}

// this function runs on the page load event after the DOM has been rendered 
// and both the map_canvas and btn elements exist.
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        originalCenter: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
// need do do this in the initialize function, after the page has loaded and the 'btn' exists
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function () {
    // Add a Marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
        map: map,
        title: 'Marker'
    });

    // Refresh
    refreshMap();
});
}

// Initialize Map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```